# Read XML File's certain value from Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Hi I use this code to save an xml file

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(isoStream, settings))
                {

                    writer.WriteStartElement("t", "test", "urn:test");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("TestA", "");
                    writer.WriteString(lbTestA.Text);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("TestB", "");
                    writer.WriteString(lbTestB.Text);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteEndDocument();

                    writer.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
```

And it created the right xml file checked with Isolated Storage Explorer for WP7, now I want to read only the values stored in the  and  Tags the only code I could use was this one

```
private void loadgame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("test.xml", FileMode.Open);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
                {
                    lsScore.DataContext = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

But it just reads the whole xml file as it is just a text, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code reading the xml file. I used a seperator between the values and later used the .Split to seperate the values

```
private void loadtest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

     IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                if (storage.FileExists("test.xml"))
                {

          IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storage.OpenFile("test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

                XDocument test = XDocument.Load(fileStream);
                 string score = test.Root.Value.ToString();

               string[] scores = score.Split(',');
               foreach (string s in scores)
               {
                  lbTestAScore.Text= scores[0].ToString();
                  lbTestBScore.Text = scores[1].ToString();
               }
```

The XML File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
  <TeamA>300</TeamA>
  <Seperator>,</Seperator>
  <TeamB>-200</TeamB>
</test>
```

The output from string `score = test.Root.Value.ToString();`

is 300,-200

I think this sums it all up.

Answer (score 0):

The reader.ReadToEnd() reads the whole file to string. If you want it as XML you have to construct an XDocument, e.g:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

then get the content you want from the XML document using LINQ.